# Jquery can't use clone on appended html

Tags: jquery, append, clone

Im using JQuery to insert HTML code into a webpage

```
<div class="title-OthProb-outer">    
        <input type="button" class="title-add-non-standard-issue" value="Add a Non Standard Problem" />
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var titleString = '<div class="title-OthProb-wrap title-nonStand1"><h3>Non Standard   Problems</h3><!-- redacted for readability! --></div><input type="button" class="title-add-another" value="+" /><br>';

$('div[class^=title-OthProb-wrap]').hide();
$('input[class^=title-add-another]').hide();
$(function() {
    $('.title-add-non-standard-issue').on('click', function() {
    $('input[class^=title-add-non-standard-issue]').hide();
       var that = this;
       var elem = $(that).closest('.title-OthProb-outer').append(titleString);
       var elem = $(that).closest('.title-OthProb-outer').find('.title-OthProb-wrap');
       $(elem).fadeIn(500);
});
```

This works fine, however I want the facility to clone the html, I had it working when the html was all in the page, i.e. not generated by Jquery, however now clicking the 'title-add-another' button does nothing.

```
$(function() {
$('.title-add-another').click(function() {
    // Add non-standard problems
    var num     = $('.title-OthProb-wrap').length; // how many "duplicatable"  fields we currently have
    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

    // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
    var newElem = $('.title-nonStand' + num).clone().attr('class', 'title-OthProb-wrap title-nonStand' + newNum);

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('.title-nonStand' + num).after(newElem);         
    });
});
```

If I enter that into the console then the button works... How does Jquery deal with elements that don't exist until after the page has been loaded?

Comment: delegation, a wonderful word (world)

Comment: am I missing something or are you trying to clone a non-existing element?

Comment: @scunliffe oh well, looks like you are right

Comment: Checking the pages event handlers shows that theres nothing set for the add-another button once its added. I'll look into delegation.

Comment: Im appending the html to the page and then trying to clone that, I may as well continue appending the html string instead of cloning it.

Comment: So this element `$('.title-nonStand' + num)` already exists when you try to clone it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delegation...

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click','.title-add-another',function () {
        // Add non-standard problems
        var num = $('.title-OthProb-wrap').length; // how many "duplicatable"  fields we currently have
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

        // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
        var newElem = $('.title-nonStand' + num).clone().attr('class', 'title-OthProb-wrap title-nonStand' + newNum);

        // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('.title-nonStand' + num).after(newElem);
    });
});
```

Comment: but you should not use document but instead the closest static container of '.title-add-another' elements, it's better